# The table does not support the 'updatedAt' system property

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I recently lost an Azure database (there's no recovering it...) and had to recreate from scratch.  This database is supposed to sync to our iOS app, which allows us to keep the data between the DB and Device in sync. Unfortunately, after recreating the database and tables manually (because I'm not sure how else to do it?), my App Service is able to connect to the SQL database, and from the app side it looks like it's syncing, but when I look at the logs, I'm seeing the following error for each table, and I get no data:

> The table '*tablename*' does not support the 'updatedAt' system
> property.

I've searched everywhere for this system property and cannot for the life of me find out where it's at or how to relate it to the database tables.

Here's an example of a schema for a table I'm having issues with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CurrentItems](
    [id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [siteID] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [residentUnitNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [residentID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [pinUsedToCheckOut] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [itemType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [itemTrackingNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [itemNotes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [itemID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [deviceSerialNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [dateRecordCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [dateLastModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [dateItemCheckedOut] [datetime] NULL,
    [dateItemCheckedIn] [datetime] NULL,
    [currentStatus] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [checkedOutEmpID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [checkedInEmpID] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [carrierName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [barcodeValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [createdAt] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [updatedAt] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CurrentItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I really need to get this app back to syncing, even if that means starting from scratch, but I can't seem to find the instructions for that on the Azure website anymore, so I don't know what else to do.

Any help or guidance anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: rename the column

Comment: If you haven't learned the lesson from this experience yet, make ssure you do; make **regular** back ups of your production databases. Yes, you've lost the data, but make sure it can never happen again.

Comment: Why would you not have had a recent backup? That's Database101. Are you sure the column names are identical to what they were previously, sounds like a conflict somewhere.

Comment: This was an old app that hadn't been touched in well over 6 years and was dead. We are recently trying to bring it back and discovered that our DB instance in Azure no longer existed. It was something I DID have on a backup, years ago, but for some reason is also long gone. Live and learn, we definitely backup our other products regularly in a reliable way, now. :)

Comment: nbk - rename the column to what? It's already named updatedAt with the correct datetimeoffset field.  I've compared this to a database that IS syncing, and I see virtually no difference in the setup. I'm confused as to why it's not working.

Comment: Googling the error message I think this is from Azure Mobile Apps framework. Maybe it expects the trigger described here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/428af758-bf03-449b-a3e9-08ca90f0d62d/mobile-services-sync-updatedat?forum=azuremobile

Comment: I googled the error too and came up with that same document, however, the other app that I have that uses the same exact sync method, does not have triggers on its tables, but I'll try and create some and see if that resolves the issue.